# Module method is not being called with ()

Tags: backbone.js

For some reason I can't get the addOne method to fire in this view. The render method fires just fine.The collection is being passed in from another module that instantiates it. When I add the parentheses to the method call it will fire but then Underscore throws an error.

```
define(['backbone',
'jquery',
'underscore',
'views/user',
'models/user',
],
function(Backbone,$,_,UserView,UserModel){

var  Users= Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'ul',
    className:'well',

    initialize:function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
    },

    render:function() {
        this.collection.each( this.addOne, this );
        return this;
    },

    addOne:function() {
        console.log('inside of addOne');
        var userView = new UserView({model:UserModel});
        this.$el.append(userView.render().el);
    }
});
return Users;
```

});

Comment: Are you sure the collection isn't empty when you `this.collection.each`? And you don't need the second argument to `each` when you've already bound all the view's methods with `_.bindAll(this)`.

Comment: Also, you probably want `addOne: function(model)` and `new UserView({model: model})`.

Comment: @muistooshort `child {models: Array[0], length: 0, _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
_byId: Object
_idAttr: "id"
length: 4
models: Array[4]`
 this is what the collection is logging to the console.

Comment: Maybe it something to do with the json response from the server?

Comment: Notice the `models: Array[0]`? And `console.log(this.collection.toJSON())` will get around async issues that can cause confusion with `console.log`.

Comment: Yeah I did the toJSON but all I got was an empty []

Comment: So your collection is empty and `this.collection.each` on an empty collection doesn't do anything. Perhaps you forgot a `fetch` call and your `render` should be bound to the collection's `"reset"` event.

Comment: I'm calling fetch in the collection's initialize method, is that bad? The collection is definitely getting populated with models as the each call is triggering the model's initialize method for every recored in the DB.

Comment: @muistooshort Finally, you were right. I had to `_bindAll(this)` and `this.collection.bind('reset',this.renderAll)` Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your UserView is a model view. This means that you need to pass to it an instance of a model and not the definition of the model's module, which is what the "UserModel" holds in your case.

Example:

```
var um = new UserModel({name: 'foo', id: 1});
var uv = new UserView({model: um}); //um is an instance of the model 'UserModel'
```

In your case, since the model objects are coming from iterating over this.collection, it would be (as correctly noted above by `mu is too short`):

```
addOne: function(m) {
    console.log('inside of addOne');
    var userView = new UserView({model: m});
    this.$el.append(userView.render().el);
}
```

Also be careful so that `this.collection` is not empty when you call render().